# ¿Es correcto decir "pelota de rugbi"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, definiciones, deportes

Si el término pelota, bola y balón hacen alusión a objetos esféricos... ¿Es correcto decir *pelota* o *balón* de rugbi? ¿No se supone que deberíamos de llamarlo únicamente *óvalo*?

Comment: maldita sea! he escrito óvalo con "b". Lo siento, se me ha ido el dedo!

Comment: Siempre puedes editar tus propios posts (los de otros también, pero un usuario de mayor reputación debe darle el visto bueno a los cambios y aprobarlos. Cuando ganes suficiente reputación, podrás editar posts de otros usuarios y proponer cambios - así que ya sabes, a postear muchas preguntas y respuestas para ganar reputación!)

Comment: yo lo llamo balón de rugby, pero pelota de rugby no me suena mal, me suena raro

Comment: Bueno, siendo rigurosos... el óvalo es una figura plana. El balón de rugby se parece más a un esferoide, jeje.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a site specific search for this on the site of the Spanish Rugby Federation (ferugby.es) We find

> *balón* 675
>   *pelota*  47
>   *bola*     7
>   *óvalo*    0

Some of the references to *bola* are to its use in a draw for a competition and not to the oval object used in the game.

Note that they use the spelling rugby in their title

Answer (score 1):

De las definiciones de pelota y balón, se puede entender que ambas son indistinguibles o intercambiables a efectos prácticos:

> [Balón](https://dle.rae.es/bal%C3%B3n?m=form)
>
> 1. m. Pelota grande, usada en juegos o con fines terapéuticos.
>
> [Pelota](https://dle.rae.es/pelota)
>
> 2. f. balón (‖ pelota grande).

Por supuesto ambas definiciones dan a entender que una pelota o balón es un objeto **esférico**. Se le denomina (o debería denominarse) de manera distinta al de ruby por no ser esférico sino ovalado? La respuesta es que no se le denomina de manera distinta, pues se entiende que la pelota o balón de rugby es un instrumento del juego como en otros deportes similares donde se le denomina pelota o balón.

En [¿Por qué la pelota de rugby es ovalada?](https://es.quizzclub.com/trivia/por-que-la-pelota-de-rugby-es-ovalada/answer/314831/) (o [¿SABES PORQUE LA PELOTA DE RUGBY ES OVALADA?](https://zentarugbyoran.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/%C2%BFsabes-porque-la-pelota-de-rugby-es-ovalada/), o cualquier otro artículo similar sobre este deporte y su peculiar balón o pelota) se explica que esta pelota estaba fabricada usando una vegija de cerdo, y eso terminó por deformar el balón.

> ¿Ovalada o deforme?
>
> La forma ovalada, en principio, se le atribuye a una causa natural. La vejiga de cerdo, con la que se construía el preciado balón, le daba una apariencia más oval que redonda a la pelota del rugby football.
>
> [...]
>
> Si bien no existe registro fehaciente de cuándo la pelota se hizo menos redonda y más oval, hay una referencia en el libro “Tom Brown’s school days” de Thomas Hughes que comenta algo referido al tamaño de la pelota de football y deja ver que la misma se había hecho más oval para 1835.
>
> Una de las versiones sobre la historia de la pelota ovalada asegura que fueron los mismos estudiantes de la Rugby School quiénes le pidieron a Gilbert que les diera otra forma a sus balones. De esta manera, buscaban diferenciar su nuevo juego del resto de los deportes
>
> Fuente: [¿SABES PORQUE LA PELOTA DE RUGBY ES OVALADA?](https://zentarugbyoran.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/%C2%BFsabes-porque-la-pelota-de-rugby-es-ovalada/)

Así que, sea de manera intencionada o casual, esta pelota o balón adquirió una forma distinta, pero como partió de una pelota o balón como en otros deportes y a efectos de juego sirve para la misma función, recibe el mismo nombre.

Yo no soy futbolero, pero sí he notado que en las retransmisiones de los partidos de fútbol a veces se le denomina *esférico* a la pelota.

> **[Esférico](https://dle.rae.es/esf%C3%A9rico)**
>
> 2. adj. Que tiene forma de esfera.
> 3. m. Dep. Balón de fútbol.

Creo que esto responde a cierta jerga del fútbol en particular, y no se hace en otros deportes como el baloncesto, aunque el balón sea por supuesto también esférico o redondo.

A la espera de que algún aficionado al rugby me corrija, en este deporte se le dice pelota o balón al objeto del juego de manera intercambiable y nadie se para a pensar en el tecnicismo de si debería llamarse de forma distinta al no ser un *esférico*. La totalidad de artículos que he consultado para responder a esta pregunta (a pesar de que incluyo solo dos de los muchos), usan de manera intercambiable "balón" y "pelota" y solo esos dos términos. No he visto ninguno que se refiera al "óvalo" de juego como otros se refieren al "esférico".

Answer (score 1):

Nosotros en España decimos balón o pelota de rugby sin problema, sin que nos suene raro quiero decir. Al final supongo que el término se puede usar para un objeto curvo aunque este no sea esférico. Especialmente si ese objeto se usa para un deporte.

Saludos!